# how to get getFragmentManager from PreferenceActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-preferences

I created  `PreferenceActivity` with button `Preference out` and appointed her event.
I need to clear the username and password (I just clear out the Preference) and go to the fragment "authorization". My fragments extends from

```
android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
```

I can not I get `getFragmentManager();` (`android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager`) from `PreferenceActivity`

```
 public class PrefActivity extends PreferenceActivity {
        Preference out;
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref);
            out = findPreference("logout");
            out.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                    Fragment auth = new AuthDialog();
                    Bundle arg = new Bundle();
                    arg.putString("login", "");
                    arg.putString("password", "");
                    auth.setArguments(arg);
                    fragmentManager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, auth).commit();
                    SharedPreferences sPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplication());
                    sPref.edit().clear().commit();
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`PreferenceActivity` extends from `android.app.Activity` and not `android.support.v4.app.Activity`. Strange as it may sound, there is no way to use v4 Fragments with PreferenceActivity. Your best bet is to use [this library](https://github.com/saik0/UnifiedPreference)